# Placing cubes in a grid is very slow (using python script)

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I'm trying to generate a scene comprising of voxels generated from a 3D data matrix.
However the script that I'm using is super slow (~1h per image), and most of the time is consumed while building the scene (pyhton loop) instead of the rendering.
Does anyone see where the problem comes from?

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np
import numpy
import scipy.io
import sys

# Data loading
inputFile = sys.argv[-2]
outputFile = sys.argv[-1]
data = scipy.io.loadmat(inputFile)['data']  
voxel_dims = np.array([256, 256, 32])
data = np.reshape(data, (voxel_dims))

# Create blender scene
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

def clear_scene(scene):
    #Clears the current scene
    for obj in scene.objects:
        scene.objects.unlink(obj)
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
    return

def base_object():
    #Creates base cube
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=0.4, location=(0,0,0))
    return scene.objects.active

colors = {  
          '_1':(1.0,0.0,0.0),
          '_2':(0.0,1.0,0.0),,
          '_3':(0.0,0.0,1.0),
         }
color_map = {
             1: '_1',
             2: '_2',
             3: '_3'
            }        

def creatematerial(name, color):
    red = color[0]
    green = color[1]
    blue = color[2]
    alpha = 1.0
    mat=(bpy.data.materials.new(name=name))    
    mat.use_nodes = True
    Diffuse_BSDF = mat.node_tree.nodes['Diffuse BSDF']
    Diffuse_BSDF.inputs[0].default_value = [red, green, blue, alpha]
    mat.diffuse_color = [red, green, blue]
    return mat

clear_scene(scene) 
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', location=(0,0,0))
empty = bpy.context.active_object
materials=dict()    
for k,v, in colors.items():
    materials[k] = creatematerial(k,v)
bo = base_object()
mesh = bo.data

# Scene creation (This is the loop that takes forever!)
for idx,label in enumerate(color_map):
    col = colors[color_map[label]]
    xx, yy, zz = np.where(data == label)
    bo.data.materials.clear()
    bo.data.materials.append(materials[color_map[label]])
    for i in range(len(xx)):
        (x,y,z) = (xx[i], yy[i], zz[i])
        thiscube = bo.copy()
        thiscube.data = thiscube.data.copy()
        scene.objects.link(thiscube)
        thiscube.location=(x,y,z)
        thiscube.parent=empty


scene.objects.unlink(bo)
bpy.data.objects.remove(bo)

# Place camera and render scene 
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(130.409,114.09,46.750),rotation=(1.201,-0.0000464,3.111))
bpy.context.object.data.clip_end = 200
point=bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT',location=(15,15,60))
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='SUN',location=(15,15,80))
bpy.context.scene.cycles.film_transparent = True
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 256
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 512
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 480
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = outputFile
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Every entry of the 3D matrix has an id which corresponds to its color. The dimension of the matrix is 256x256x32, however only a subset of the voxels is occupied.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the code creates for each data point a seperate Blender Mesh Object. For large datasets this will make everything super slow.
I would recommend you to create only one mesh per label-class so that with 3 label classes you would have only 3 Mesh Objects.

Since you are actually using my code, I took your question as feedback and updated it accordingly on github.
https://github.com/cagcoach/BlenderPlot